# How can I make my animation state manager work in unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am changing the animation state using code and mobile joystick input.

```
if (joystick.Vertical > joystick.Horizontal)
    { 
        if (joystick.Vertical > threshhold) //Forward
        {
            foreach (AnimatorControllerParameter parameter in animator.parameters)
                if (parameter.type == AnimatorControllerParameterType.Bool)
                    animator.SetBool(parameter.name, false);
            animator.SetBool("isRunningForward", true);
        }
        else if(joystick.Vertical < -threshhold) //Backward
        {
            foreach (AnimatorControllerParameter parameter in animator.parameters)
                if (parameter.type == AnimatorControllerParameterType.Bool)
                    animator.SetBool(parameter.name, false);
            animator.SetBool("isRunningBackward", true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (joystick.Horizontal > threshhold) //Right
        {
            foreach (AnimatorControllerParameter parameter in animator.parameters)
                if (parameter.type == AnimatorControllerParameterType.Bool)
                    animator.SetBool(parameter.name, false);
            animator.SetBool("isRunningRight", true);
        }
        else if (joystick.Horizontal < -threshhold) //Left
        {
            foreach (AnimatorControllerParameter parameter in animator.parameters)
                if (parameter.type == AnimatorControllerParameterType.Bool)
                    animator.SetBool(parameter.name, false);
            animator.SetBool("isRunningLeft", true);
        }
    }
    if(Mathf.Abs(joystick.Vertical) < 0.5 && Mathf.Abs(joystick.Horizontal) < 0.5)
    {
        foreach (AnimatorControllerParameter parameter in animator.parameters)
            if (parameter.type == AnimatorControllerParameterType.Bool)
                animator.SetBool(parameter.name, false);

    }
```

For some reason "isRunningBackwards" and "isRunningLeft" aren't working properly.

When I move the joystick back the left animation state is turned on [screenshot of my editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIcii.png)

Comment: The problem is in the first line. It doesn't account properly for negative numbers which is why it doesn't do backwards and left properly. In the image we can see that vertical is -0.9 and  horizontal is -0.03 therefore vertical is LESS than horizontal and the code will go down to the right and left parts. What I would do is change the first line to `if(Mathf.Abs(joystick.Vertical) > Mathf.Abs(joystick.Horizontal))` so that their values are made positive when compared.

Comment: Thank you. That is just what I was missing. Works Perfectly now